# How to track google ads conversion on desktop app install

Tags: chromium, google-ads-api

I have a desktop app for Windows. it's written in C++. We're promoting the software using Google Adwords.

We would like to count installations of the software as a conversion on Google Ads, so the algorithm can optimize for it. But all I can find is for Mobile Apps, hooking up with Firebase or Google Analytics, but in the set up it's asking for App ID's on Google Play or Apple's AppStore which doesn't fit my case.

Has anyone done this before? or could some point in the right direction?

I haven't tried the standard pixel approach, because cookies are in the browser that generates the download, but not in the installed software itself, so there is no way for attribution to work correctly

Comment: The language used to write your app is a sideshow for a question like this so I pulled the C++ tag.

Comment: Thought it was important to consider if there was any c++ library I could add

Comment: You can make that more clear in the question and add the tag back, but there is a caveat: Requests for library suggestions are off topic on Stack Overflow, so the search for a library should not be the main thrust of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option here is to use Google Analytics if you can. You can use the measurement protocol with GA to send the conversion, then import your GA conversions into Google Ads.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4

The UA version is pretty stable, but the new one linked above is working well too.